# Subselect query using mysql_query not possible

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I tried to write a SQL query with a subselect like this:

```
SELECT pages.uid FROM pages WHERE title = '01' AND pid = (SELECT uid FROM pages WHERE title = '2014' AND pid = 280);
```

When I paste this query into the PHPMyAdmin interface it executes without problem. But when I use the PHP function "mysql_query" it doesnt work and return FALSE.

A collegue of mine told me that there is something built in PHP which prevents you from calling such subqueries, using multiple SELECT in SELECT in SELECT ... statements.

Is it possible to allow such a query, with at least one subquery?

EDIT: 
This is the PHP code I use to execute the query:

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery, $this->databaseHandle);
```

PHP tells me that there is an error executing mysql_query. It returns false instead of the resource. Any chances to find out more about the error?

EDIT 2: 
I use PHP 5.5.10 and MySQL Version 14.14.

Comment: I don't believe there is such a restriction.  You should include the code that you are actually running in your question.

Comment: I think the problem may be related to your hybridization of the PDO and (deprecated) mysql_ APIs

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand your comment. Anything I could do about this?